# Conditionally colour cells in an htmlTable based on categorical values. Table displays dynamically on user input (r shiny0

Tags: r, html-table, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I've created an app that allows user to select an electoral division and then a table is updated showing all the political parties which had been voted into power over the years.

I would like to color the cells containing the political party abbreviations with the corresponding party color.
[image of example table showing colored cells based on categorical value (party abbreviation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTzhA.png)

```
 Example data:
     Elect_div<-c("Blair","Bonner","Bowman","Brisbane","Capricornia","Dawson","Dickson")
     Elected_party_2016<-c("ALP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP)
     Elected_party_2013<-c("ALP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP)

     df.party <- data.frame(Elect_div, Elected_party_2016, Elected_party_2013)
     # i need the table in long format as the real data goes back to 2004 and 
     the table displays below a map and some graphs
     df.melted<-melt(df.party, idvars="Elect_div", measure.vars=c("Elected_party_2016", "Elected_party_2013"))
     #removing varible column as I am manually setting the row names within the htmlTable below
     df.melted$variable <- NULL
     #bring the valu column to the first position
     df.melted<-df.melted[,c(ncol(df.melted),1:(ncol(df.melted)-1))]

     #shiny app

     ui<- fluidPage(
             selectInput("division", "",
          label="Select an electorate, graphs below will be updated.",
          choices = df.melted$Elect_div),
          htmlOutput("table"))

     server <- function(input, output, session) {  
           selectedData<-eventReactive(df.melted$Elect_div==input$division,  {

           HTML(
             htmlTable(subset(df.melted,df.melted$Elect_div==input$division), 
             align="l",
             header=c("",""),
             rnames= paste(c("Party elected 2016","Party elected 2013")), 
            caption="Historic elected party data from the Australian Electoral Commission (AEC)",
             tfoot="&dagger;Participation & Unemployment rate calculated using data from Australian Government Dept of Jobs & Small Business (2018)"

              ))

                    })
                 output$table <- renderUI({selectedData()})

                      }

                  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now my question is how do I set the background colour of the cells to match the party colors if:

```
                party_cols<-c("LNP"="blue","ALP" = "red","IND" = "grey", "KAP = "purple")
```

I've tried a bunch of different options based on what I have read here but none work (kable, col.rgroup, background = , cell_apec).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you want ?

[image]

```
Elect_div<-c("Blair","Bonner","Bowman","Brisbane","Capricornia","Dawson","Dickson")
Elected_party_2016<-c("ALP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP")
Elected_party_2013<-c("ALP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP")

df.party <- data.frame(Elect_div, Elected_party_2016, Elected_party_2013)
# i need the table in long format as the real data goes back to 2004 and the table displays below a map and some graphs
df.melted<- reshape2::melt(df.party, idvars="Elect_div", measure.vars=c("Elected_party_2016", "Elected_party_2013"))
#removing varible column as I am manually setting the row names within the htmlTable below
df.melted$variable <- NULL
#bring the valu column to the first position
df.melted<-df.melted[,c(ncol(df.melted),1:(ncol(df.melted)-1))]

party_cols<-c("LNP"="blue","ALP" = "red","IND" = "grey", "KAP" = "purple")

library(shiny)
library(htmlTable)

ui<- fluidPage(
  selectInput("division", "",
              label="Select an electorate, graphs below will be updated.",
              choices = df.melted$Elect_div),
  htmlOutput("table"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {  
  selectedData<-eventReactive(df.melted$Elect_div==input$division,  {
    dat <- subset(df.melted,df.melted$Elect_div==input$division)
    party <- dat$value[1]
    HTML(
      htmlTable(
        dat, 
        align="l",
        header=c("",""),
        rnames= paste(c("Party elected 2016","Party elected 2013")), 
        css.cell = rep(sprintf("background-color: %s;", party_cols[party]), 2),
        caption="Historic elected party data from the Australian Electoral Commission (AEC)",
        tfoot="&dagger;Participation & Unemployment rate calculated using data from Australian Government Dept of Jobs & Small Business (2018)"
      ))

  })
  output$table <- renderUI({selectedData()})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## UPDATE

```
Elect_div<-c("Blair","Bonner","Bowman","Brisbane","Capricornia","Dawson","Dickson")
Elected_party_2016<-c("ALP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP")
Elected_party_2013<-c("ALP","KAP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP","LNP")

df.party <- data.frame(Elect_div, Elected_party_2016, Elected_party_2013)
# i need the table in long format as the real data goes back to 2004 and the table displays below a map and some graphs
df.melted<- reshape2::melt(df.party, idvars="Elect_div", measure.vars=c("Elected_party_2016", "Elected_party_2013"))
#removing varible column as I am manually setting the row names within the htmlTable below
df.melted$variable <- NULL
#bring the valu column to the first position
df.melted<-df.melted[,c(ncol(df.melted),1:(ncol(df.melted)-1))]

party_cols<-c("LNP"="blue","ALP" = "red","IND" = "grey", "KAP" = "purple")

library(shiny)
library(htmlTable)

ui<- fluidPage(
  selectInput("division", "",
              label="Select an electorate, graphs below will be updated.",
              choices = df.melted$Elect_div),
  htmlOutput("table"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {  
  selectedData<-eventReactive(df.melted$Elect_div==input$division,  {
    dat <- subset(df.melted,df.melted$Elect_div==input$division)
    HTML(
      htmlTable(
        dat, 
        align="l",
        header=c("",""),
        rnames= paste(c("Party elected 2016","Party elected 2013")), 
        css.cell = t(vapply(party_cols[dat$value], function(x) rep(sprintf("background-color: %s;", x), 2), character(2))),
        caption="Historic elected party data from the Australian Electoral Commission (AEC)",
        tfoot="&dagger;Participation & Unemployment rate calculated using data from Australian Government Dept of Jobs & Small Business (2018)"
      ))

  })
  output$table <- renderUI({selectedData()})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, Yes this is exactly what I want. I just need to change the font to white so you can read it! Thank you :)

Comment: @RhettaC `party <- dat$value[1]` in `selectedData`.

Comment: The issue is though that when there are different parties that have been elected throughout the years the colour is based on a column not the row I think so if 2016= ALP (red), 2013=ALP(red), 2010=LP(blue) the whole column is coloured red instead of red, red, blue if that makes sense.

Comment: @RhettaC You mean the 2013 party can be different from the 2016 party?

Comment: Here is a link to the test app: https://regionalinnovationdatalab.shinyapps.io/test/    so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Yes, exactly, and in the real app with the full data going back to 2004 there can be a lot of change within the selected electorate. Some there is no change at all and the example data I provided in the example probably doesn't have much change between 2016 - 2013 so your answer worked for the example data.

Comment: @RhettaC Ok. I will try. Please wait.

Comment: @RhettaC See my update. Is it ok now ? I had to change the `css.cell` option.

Comment: PS: there's a warning generated by the line `df.melted<- reshape2::melt` but I think it has no serious consequence.

Comment: Yes it works! You are amazing, I spent a whole afternoon trying to figure that out. Thank you :)